# Multipeer: Is it possible to have independent UIScrollViews?

Tags: uiscrollview, swift4, multipeer-connectivity

I have a Multipeer application (only a single app) that allows the host to present an image and then draw on it.

The peers receive the image as it changes.

The image is presented in a UIScrollView on both types of modes.

The host can currently pan the image, and zoom in and out.

However the host would like to be able to do the same, perhaps to view a different part of a larger image than is being edited.

Is this at all possible? Right now both modes use the same code except when setting the scroll views image view. The host loads the image from his own device, while the peer copies the image from the data sent through the Multipeer connection.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

At home now so I can add some code.

The various functions that deal with the UIScrollView. imageView is a custom UIImageView that has a couple of properties, one of them being mapSizeRatio that deals with the ratio of the original image versus the screen density to deal with rotation and various devices.

```
  func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return imageView
  }

  func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let imageViewSize = imageView.frame.size
    let scrollViewSize = bounds.size

    let verticalPadding = imageViewSize.height < scrollViewSize.height ? (scrollViewSize.height - imageViewSize.height) / 2 : 0
    let horizontalPadding = imageViewSize.width < scrollViewSize.width ? (scrollViewSize.width - imageViewSize.width) / 2 : 0

    contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: verticalPadding, left: horizontalPadding, bottom: verticalPadding, right: horizontalPadding)
  }

  /// maximum zoom should be based on the 1-inch square concept
  public func setZoomScaleForScrollView() {
    let imageViewSize = imageView.bounds.size
    let scrollViewSize = bounds.size
    let widthScale = scrollViewSize.width / imageViewSize.width
    let heightScale = scrollViewSize.height / imageViewSize.height

    minimumZoomScale = max(widthScale, heightScale)
    maximumZoomScale = imageView.mapSizeRatio
  }
```

and in the View Controller

```
  override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    mapScrollView.setZoomScaleForScrollView()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

After a night's rest and then debugging EVERYTHING in my app, I discovered something "odd?".

The viewWillLayoutSubviews of the View Controller does not fire on the Peer once the app is running and receiving images from the Host.

So it was a simple case of performing a view.setNeedsLayout() when the Peer receives an image update.

However this was not so intuitive to me ... if the imageView changes, shouldn't the scrollView say "hey" something has changed ... and thus trigger the viewController to think "hey I need to update"?

Anyways, I hope this helps others who are thinking of doing something similar.